# How can I compare value-types acquired from Reflection's "GetValue"?

Tags: c#, reflection, equality

I have this code which gets the value from the Test class and then converts it to the type it is. It prints correctly as "Int32" but when I test the equality with another variable with the same value, it prints "false". I suspect it is because it is testing reference equality and that the 2 variables are really still objects.
Is there any way to compare them, keeping in mind I won't know the type of the value returned until runtime (it could be a string, float, other class, etc.)?

```
class Test{public int y;}

static void Main()
{
    var test1 = new Test{y=1};
    var test2 = new Test{y=1};
    var fields = test1.GetType().GetFields();
    var test1Value = fields[0].GetValue(test1);
    var test2Value = fields[0].GetValue(test2);
    var test1Converted = Convert.ChangeType(test1Value, test1Value.GetType());
    var test2Converted = Convert.ChangeType(test2Value, test2Value.GetType());
    Console.WriteLine(test1Converted); // prints Int32
    Console.WriteLine(test1Converted == test2Converted); // prints false
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calls to `Convert` are unnecessary. The values returned by `GetValue` are already `int`s. Simply casting them gives the correct result.

```
private class Test
{
    public int y;
}

private static void Main()
{
    Test test1 = new Test { y = 1 };
    Test test2 = new Test { y = 1 };
    FieldInfo[] fields = test1.GetType().GetFields();
    int test1Value = (int)fields[0].GetValue(test1);
    int test2Value = (int)fields[0].GetValue(test2);
    Console.WriteLine(test1Value); // prints Int32
    Console.WriteLine(test1Value == test2Value); // prints true
}
```

The reason that the un-casted values fails is that `Convert.ChangeType` still returns an `object`, which [boxes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx) the ints, so you do indeed get reference equality.

Another way to get the correct value is to call the `Equals` method, which will be correctly routed to `Int32.Equals`, and print `true`:

```
Console.WriteLine(test1Converted.Equals(test2Converted)); // prints true
```

Note that in this case the `Convert.ChangeType` is still not necessary.

Comment: Equals would fail for the reference types, here it is successful for the value / integer type, as it does the value compare, this needs explicit overriding of the Equals method

Comment: @MrinalKamboj Can you give a specific example where a reference type would fail? All reference types *already* default to reference equality and will not be boxed by `GetValue`.

Comment: As you suggested, Reference equals refers to reference equality, for the default Equals method, so its not necessary that two fetched reference types variable via reflection would point to the same reference, it would need explicit overriding of Equals method to compare the intrinsic value for the current answer

Comment: @MrinalKamboj That's true, but not relevant to the question asked.

Comment: _"types already default to reference equality"_ -- and in addition, if the reference type implements some other type of equality, it will override (should have overridden) the `Equals()` method. In other words, `Equals()` works even there as well. IMHO, given the OP's question _"I won't know the type of the value returned until runtime"_, the primary answer really just should be to use `Equals()`. Casting to `int` is a distraction in this context.

Comment: @ Jason Watkins it is not valid till a reference type is introduced :), OP might be trying to resolve just a current issue and may have to post another question for the future issue

Answer (score 1):

Convert.ChangeType() return object. Cast the returned object to Int32:

```
    var test1Converted = (Int32)Convert.ChangeType(test1Value, test1Value.GetType());
    var test2Converted = (Int32)Convert.ChangeType(test2Value, test2Value.GetType());
```

Edit for comment:
Test if the type is IComparable, and then use that interface to do the comparison:

```
    if (test1Converted is IComparable && test2Converted is IComparable)
    {
      var test1IComparable = (IComparable)test1Converted;
      var test2IComparable = (IComparable)test2Converted;

      bool equal = (test1IComparable == test2IComparable);
    }
```

Comment: I can't cast because I don't know what the type of the object is until runtime. It could be a string or another class.

Comment: Ah, right, well then it gets more complicated :) You can test to see if the values are IComparable; if so, cast to IComparable, and then .CompareTo(other).

Comment: @SupremeGrandRuler: If you want `32f` to equal `32L`, you have problems.  Otherwise, just call `Equals()`.